# Python string excessive memory

Tags: python, string

I noticed, while working with large .txt files, that the memory necessary for python to store them in a string variable was huge compared to the size of the .txt files. I made this script :

```
import time
@profile
def func():
    with open('full_it_cc100/it.txt_part_0001.txt','r') as f:
        stringu = f.read()
    return stringu

stringu = func()
print("I HAVE STRINGU")
time.sleep(3)
```

I profiled it using memory-profiler(see footnote), and I can see that after func() is finished executing, it utilizes 2Gb of memory. The .txt file in question contains italian text, and weighs 500Mb. I have no idea how the string size could be inflated 4x the size of the initial .txt.

Note that if I read as binary instead ('r'->'rb'), then I find that it occupies 600Mb after func() executed, which makes much more sense.

Could it be simply due to the encoding ? But 4 times the size seems to be a bit excessive no?

To answer some of the further questions :
I am using python 3.10.11, and the platform is CPython.

`print(len(stringu))`, `print(stringu.__sizeof__())` and `print(sorted(set(map(ord, stringu))))` yield respectively :

- 517122251
- 2068489080
- https://pastebin.com/bMYcK3Zm

If you want to download the .txt file and try to reproduce :
https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/815a168d-d818-4da3-9c83-462211c2f58d

EDIT : I took (albeit from another dataset) a file of english text of around 500 Mb, and applied the same script to it. I find that it uses 1Gb of memory approx, and respectively the 3 print statements yield:

- 523598410
- 1047196894
- https://pastebin.com/d4dG5NAm

So indeed, there might be something fishy going on with the 'italian' files, which maybe be due to the way I split them, or to the fact they come from a different dataset. I will test some more stuff.

**To run the same exact script `pip install memory-profiler` and then `mprof run script_name.py`. Alternatively, you can just remove the decorator and run it normally.**

Comment: utf-8 characters can be 4 bytes.  Not sure if that is at play here or not.

Comment: Sure, can be, but in that case we would need every single character to be 4 bytes to get that, no ? In italian, there are a few 'non-standard' characters, like with accents and so one, but I would say its less than 5%.

I will try it on english text to see if there is a big difference !

Comment: What version of Python are you using? and are you using CPython or another implementation? Just want to check before someone tries to test this in case it's version-specific.

Comment: I am using Python 3.10.11, not sure about the CPython thing ? I just installed in the standard way using sudo apt install. How could I check ?

Comment: If you are memory constrained, perhaps there is a way to work with your data in smaller chunks.

Comment: I know, and I am working in smaller chunks, I am more curious about why does it behave this way.

Comment: What do `print(len(stringu))`, `print(stringu.__sizeof__())` and 
`print(sorted(set(map(ord, stringu))))` show?

Comment: @Frotaur OK, you're almost definitely using CPython then; that's the standard implementation. But btw if you want to check, [you can use `platform.python_implementation()`](/a/14718168/4518341)

Comment: What's `profile`? I'm not finding it in `cProfile` or `profile` stdlib modules.

Comment: Also, you can remove the dependency on `time`. If you need a terminal window to stay open, there are other ways to do that that don't involve Python code, like for example, starting a terminal then running the code from there. For more advice, see [mre].

Comment: @KellyBundy Oh, mb, I didn't know that was a package. It'd help to add the import though, to be clear. (Should be `from memory_profiler import profile`?)

Comment: @wjandrea this was just so that the memory profiler had the time to output how much memory was used at the end of the processing. But I don't think it makes a big difference. And yes, this decorator works only when running the script with mprof run 'script_name.py'

Comment: Storing multi-byte characters with 4-bytes each is very, _very_ typical (so, _serializing_ to UTF-8, but _working_ as UTF-32). Allows much faster random access to have 100% of your characters be a full 4 bytes than needing to start from the front and work back to figure out how long each character is. As such, I would call this normal, not excessive; if you want 1:1 with your on-disk size (but for the regular object overhead), store it as a bytestring, not a string of codepoints; you lose the ability to do random access by codepoint indices, but that's what's expensive to optimize for.

Comment: You have some unusually high code points. Are you sure you're using the correct encoding?

Comment: The file is encoded utf-8 as far as I can tell. I have one possible problem, is that I split a big file at exactly the 500Mb mark, so it might make a strange ending to the file, but beyond that, there should not be too much weird stuff ?

Although @CharlesDuffy answer makes sense, since it would explain the almost exact four-fold increase in size.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think PyPy uses UTF-8 for it's strings, but I don't remember how they make random access etc fast...

Comment: Looking at the characters, I see plenty of characters from multiple Asian countries (I think) and other stuff I wouldn't expect from "italian text". Including many code points below 32.

Comment: @KellyBundy, ...about 20 years ago I built a data structure that used a tree with each level calculating offsets into a buffer; I could imagine adopting that for fast access to UTF-8, but the fact that I can think of a way to do it doesn't mean it's the approach anyone _actually used_ in practice :)

Comment: The https://pastebin.com/bMYcK3Zm result is the only necessary diagnostic here. The file does not only contain Italian text; it contains emoji and private-use characters, and quite a few Han characters. The former will require expanding the string to a 4-byte-per-character representation internally, and the Han characters would still require a 2-byte-per-character representation. The in-memory representation **must** use a constant number of bytes per character in order to be able to support constant-time indexing. Please see the linked duplicate, which in turn cites the relevant PEP.

Comment: @KellyBundy pypy builds an index lazily, IIRC it doesn't actually provide O(1) access but it's close enough for most intents and purposes, and doesn't suffer from the memory explosion issue of FSR.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, thank you for the link. It seems to be indeed the answer to the question, although not directly. What you are saying is that the python representatin will fall back to the 'worst' character, to have constant time indexing ? If so, i believe there is still a difference in my question and the 'duplicate one'.

Comment: It will, and the duplicate does explain this indirectly: "Python 3.3 switched to a new internal representation, using the most compact form *needed to represent all characters* in a string." (Emphasis mine.)

Comment: Is there a URL for the actual file? The swisstransfer thing seems to require me to download with a browser.

Comment: Yes for the italian file : https://data.statmt.org/cc-100/. Its the first 500 megabytes of the dataset for italian

Comment: Is it possible to reopen this question? I'd like to answer it.

Comment: You can quadruple the size of a string in memory compared to its size on disk by adding a single character to it. This is because UTF8 uses “variable-width encoding” whereas Python uses “fixed-width encoding”. Take a string with 1000 × 1-B chars. It will use 1 kB in both Python and UTF8. Now add a 4-B char to this string. It will now use 1004 B in UTF8, but 4004 B in Python. So the ratio is ~4. On the contrary, if you take a 1000 × 4-B string and you add a 1-B char, you end up with a ratio of ~1. Your file contains 6E12 × more 1-B chars than 4-B chars, so that’s why you get a ratio of ~4.